# What would a TV host say to his guest when the time for the show is about to end?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, sentence-choice

What would a TV host say to his guest when the time for the show is about to end?

> Our time is low/short. Can you answer the last question in 20 seconds?

What are the other possible variations?

---

I hope I can ask another question here in order to prevent opening another thread.
How can I say something gives good news about future. What is the exact word?

> This report ...... a good year. (declares? proves? .....)

Comment: " we are a little short on time..." , "a little behind the program schedule"..."TIme is running out.." "the report anticipates / expects maybe"

Comment: Please make another post for your second question. One question per post, unless they are closely related (usually a follow-up). There is no problem making another post. Users do it all the time.

Comment: @MK Do you think I could use **promise** in the second situation. I just find it accidentally

Comment: Also, consider [waiting longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer.

Comment: Yes promise is your best bet. It slipped my mind.

Comment: Or maybe **our time is almost up...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that it is idiomatic to say that time itself is short or low in this case. Instead, you can say that *we are short on time*. I don't think *we are low on time* is as common, at least according to [this ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=low+on+time%2C+short+on+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clow%20on%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshort%20on%20time%3B%2Cc0).

You can also say *we're almost out of time*, which I think is clear, or you can also say *we are running out of time*.

> [running out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/run-out)
>   3. [intransitive] if time is running out, you do not have long to do something